# Adding a property to an array of objects from another array

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this with names and address:

```
BTDevices = [
{name:"n1", address:"add1"},
{name:"n2", address:"add2"},
{name:"n3", address:"add3"}]
```

And another array with alias and address:

```
EqAlias = [
{btAlias:"a1", address:"add0"},
{btAlias:"a2", address:"add2"},
{btAlias:"a3", address:"add9"}]
```

I want to add btAlias property to all objects in BTDevices and set the value only if the address are the same, for example in this case I want the following result:

BTDevices:

```
name:"n1", address:"add1", btAlias:""
name:"n2", address:"add2", btAlias:"a2"
name:"n3", address:"add3", btAlias:""
```

My first solution was adding btAlias property using forEach and then using two for loops:

```
// Add Alias
this.BTDevices.forEach(function(obj) { obj.btAlias = "" });

// Set Alias
for (let m = 0; m < this.EqAlias.length; m ++)
{
  for (let n = 0; n < this.BTDevices.length; n++)
  {
    if (this.BTDevices[n].address == this.EqAlias[m].address)
      this.BTDevices[n].btAlias = this.EqAlias[m].btAlias;
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to do the same? I guess using forEach

Comment: What's wrong with your current approach?

Comment: Yes you could use forEach, but the finality has no differences. Using forEach might just be more readable that's all.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map` and `find`

Use `map` to loop the array and create a new array.

Use `find` to check if a string is in an array.

```js
let BTDevices = [{name:"n1", address:"add1"},{name:"n2", address:"add2"},{name:"n3", address:"add3"}];
let EqAlias = [{btAlias:"a1", address:"add0"},{btAlias:"a2", address:"add2"},{btAlias:"a3", address:"add9"}];
 
let result = BTDevices.map( v => {
   v.btAlias = ( EqAlias.find( e => e.address == v.address ) || { btAlias:"" } ).btAlias;
   return v;
});
 
console.log( result );
```

Please check doc: [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Answer (score 2):

Using `forEach` instead of `for` will just replace the two for loop with `forEach`. We could argue on which is the best between `for` and `forEach` but i don't think there's a good answer. In modern javascript you can also use the `for of` loop.

Your algorithm is the simpliest and it will work.

But, if you want to address some performances issues, you should want to know that your algorithm is also the slowest (O(n²) complexity)

Another way to do that is to store items of `BTDevices` in a map to find them faster. Example:

```
let map = new Map();
BTDevices.forEach(e => map.set(e.address, e));

EqAlias.forEach(e => {
    let device = map.get(e.address);

    if (device) {
        device.btAlias = e.btAlias;
    }
});
```

The only advantage of this code is that looking for an item in a Map is faster (between O(1) and O(n), it depends of `Map` implementation). But you won't see any differences unless you try to manipulate some very big arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do something like this.

```js
var BTDevices = [{name:"n1", address:"add1"},{name:"n2", address:"add2"},{name:"n3", address:"add3"}];
var EqAlias = [{btAlias:"a1", address:"add0"},{btAlias:"a2", address:"add2"},{btAlias:"a3", address:"add9"}];
var EqAliasAdd = EqAlias.map((e)=>e.address);
var BTDevicesAdd = BTDevices.map((e)=>e.address);
BTDevicesAdd.map(function(i,k) {
   BTDevices[k].btAlias = "";
   if(EqAliasAdd.indexOf(i) >= 0)
      BTDevices[k].btAlias = EqAlias[k].btAlias;
});
console.log(BTDevices);
```